# Running mysqldump through Python's subprocess module is slow and verbose

Tags: python, mysql, import, subprocess

```
@cost_time
def dbdump_all():
    "导出数据库所有数据至当前目录下以年月日命名的sql文件"
    filename=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    cmd="""mysqldump -u root -pzhoubt --opt --quick --database search > ./%s.sql"""%filename
    args=shlex.split(cmd)
    p=subprocess.Popen(args)
    #stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    #print stdout,stderr
    print "已将数据库表结构和数据导出到%s"%filename
```

I use the `mysqldump` command in a subprocess, and it outputs a lot of information about the exported data, even if I comment out the `stdout, stderr = p.communicate()` line. It's also very slow, even though I've tried the same command in a shell and it's very quick and succinct. How can I avoid all the verbosity when using `subprocess`, and speed up the time it takes to be more like running it directly from a shell?

Comment: i have finished it by myself add a argument on subprocess(shell=True)

Comment: If adding `shell=True` fixes it you can add that as an answer on your own question and accept it in two days

Comment: sorry,for my carefuless,it still didn't work,although it didn't show verbose info,but i didn't find the result sql file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@cost_time
def dbdump_all():
    "导出数据库所有数据至当前目录下以年月日命名的sql文件"
    filename=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+".sql"
    cmd="""mysqldump -u root -pzhoubt --opt --quick --database search >./%s"""%filename
    print cmd
    p=subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,cwd=os.getcwd())
    sts = os.waitpid(p.pid, 0)[1]
    print "返回状态%s"%sts
    print "已将数据库表结构和数据导出到%s"%filename
```

finally i got it,
the key is us os.waitpid to wait mysql processing,
another point is when you use shell the cmd is a string not a list